# shared data stored in memory in a cluster on tomcat based app

Tags: java, tomcat7, shared-memory

I'm writing a Tomcat 7 Java application that uses websockets.

this Java application will be on amazon EC2 cluster behind a load balancer the app itself will be on around 2-5 servers.

I have some classes that holds online users and I would like to know if it's possible to share that information around my cluster.

is memcached a solution? can the data there be shared between a cluster? 
never used memcached. just a guess

or should I change my code to store everything in database so the data will be shared among the servers?

what's the most efficient solution to overcome this problem?

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Yes, memcached would do this, but check if it works on EC2. Of course, there are others. Storing in a database is very reliable but perhaps not the most efficient. If your a hibernate person, then database storage is fine.

Answer (score 0):

welp memcached is the answer. simple as that.

Amazon ec2 provides memcached based cluster that can be used with memcached api (spymemcached) or with their own implementation (that actually uses spymemcached) called elastiCache-java-cluster-client that can audio detects memcached nodes.